# Clip raster by mask layer returns error "wrong number of parameters"

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, clip

Using Python for QGIS 2.14 Essen i try to clip a raster by a Polygon, as indicated here:
http://docs.qgis.org/2.6/de/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction/cliprasterbymasklayer.html

with this code:

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', input, mask, no_data,     alpha_band, keep_resolution, extra, output)
```

My code read as following:

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', inputlayer, maskshape, "none", False, False, "", outputraster)
```

Exactly as derived from tutorials. However, this is the error message returned and I can't figure why:
Error: Wrong number of parameters

I´ve adapted the code to the 16 parameters of the new version, although I´m not sure if correct

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', inputlayer, maskshape, "", False, False, False, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, 0, False, "",  "outputraster")
```

The error message says still the same.

Comment: Have you tried to replace "none" with ""?

Comment: yes, same response

Comment: Using Processing version 2.12.2, the algorithm is said to have 16 parameters. You can check this from the Python Console by typing: `processing.alghelp("gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer")`. Before this version it was 7 parameters, I guess it has been updated to include the _advanced parameters_ shown in the GUI version.

Comment: ok thanks, i´ll check for 2.14 then. Python is very new to me.

Comment: @PhilippDahlem - Don't confuse QGIS version with the _Processing_ plugin version (I did!). The _Processing_ plugin contains the algorithm you mentioned along with many others. You have QGIS 2.14 but the _Processing_ plugin itself may be the latest version (2.12.2).

Comment: Try adding another `0` between the 4 `0`'s in the middle. I count 15 parameters instead of 16 ;)

Comment: true tho ;) now it only shows wrong parameter value 0. is 0 actually entered correct? or has it to be in brackets, or quotation marks?

Comment: @PhilippDahlem I tried out the code you have mentioned.. it doesn't even generate an raster file i.e the output raster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following parameters requires a minimum value of 1:

- JPEGCOMPRESSION
- ZLEVEL
- PREDICTOR

The others can be set to 0 so you could try running the following which works for me:

```
processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', inputlayer, maskshape, "", False, False, False, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, False, 0, False, "", "outputraster")
```

Comment: Thanks,this is how i actually made it yesterday, after lots of Try and Error. However i also had to set the frist three boolean operators to True, for whatever reason, to get an correctly clipped raster with non-zero values. Now the raster ends up with a fourth band, but whatever..it works and I am happy. Thank you!

Comment: @PhilippDahlem - Most welcome buddy, glad it worked eventually =)

Answer (score 0):

The solution above didn't work me with QGIS 2.18.20. Still not enough parameters although the documentation says something different.

My solution:
Do it with the graphical modeler (Processing -> Graphical modeler) and than export it as python script.