# PyQGIS: gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer new options?

Tags: pyqgis

I have had used gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer function in PyQGIS many times before but with the latest update there seems to be a lot more extra arguments and I can't figure out how to get the algorithm to function properly anymore.

processing.alghelp('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer') returns the following:

> ALGORITHM: Clip raster by mask layer
>   INPUT < ParameterRaster>
>   MASK < ParameterVector>
>   NO_DATA < ParameterString>
>   ALPHA_BAND < ParameterBoolean>
>   CROP_TO_CUTLINE < ParameterBoolean>
>   KEEP_RESOLUTION < ParameterBoolean>
>   RTYPE < ParameterSelection>
>   COMPRESS < ParameterSelection>
>   JPEGCOMPRESSION < ParameterNumber>
>   ZLEVEL < ParameterNumber>
>   PREDICTOR < ParameterNumber>
>   TILED < ParameterBoolean>
>   BIGTIFF < ParameterSelection>
>   TFW < ParameterBoolean>
>   EXTRA < ParameterString>
>   OUTPUT < OutputRaster>
>
> RTYPE(Output raster type)     0 - Byte    1 - Int16   2 - UInt16  3 - UInt32
>     4 - Int32   5 - Float32     6 - Float64

COMPRESS(GeoTIFF options. Compression type:)   0 - NONE    1 - JPEG    2 - LZW     3 - PACKBITS    4 -
 DEFLATE

BIGTIFF(Control whether the created file is a BigTIFF or a classic TIFF)    0 -     1 - YES     2 - NO  3 - IF_NEEDED   4 - IF_SAFER

---

Are 16 options really needed to clip a raster? Is there a simpler option via Python? I need it for batch processing.

My best attempt got an output, but there is nothing in the file.
processing.runalg('gdalogr:cliprasterbymasklayer', rstrData, shp, 'none', False, True, True, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, True, 0, True, "", rstrOutput+str(rstrData))

Can anyone explain to me where I'm going wrong please?

https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_extraction/cliprasterbymasklayer.html

Docs are out of date to reflect this new algorithm.

Last version was a lot easier to control.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Clip raster by mask layer returns error “wrong number of parameters”](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191545/clip-raster-by-mask-layer-returns-error-wrong-number-of-parameters)